# How to Apply CSS Style Code into My Custom TextView in Android

Tags: android, css, textview, stylesheet, android-custom-view

I want to apply CSS code to My Custom Textview.

I had try to make like,

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("database content will be here in HTML format"));
```

and I would like to display CSS code into this.

Comment: For applying your custom css code you have to use WebView with loadDataWithBaseURL() instead of TextView : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Use native CSS library http://nativecss.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try this :

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p font-color="blue">database content will be here in HTML format</p>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Something like this might help you.

```
textview.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p font-color="blue">database content will be here in HTML format</p>"));
```

Comment: @raviDev Posted a very nice Link Thanks